# Matrices and Galois groups

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, galois-theory

Let $L\supseteq K$ be a finite-dimensional Galois extension with Galois group $G = \{\varphi_1,\ldots, \varphi_n\}$. Let $l_1,\ldots, l_n$ be a basis for $L$ over $K$. Prove that the matrix $(\varphi_i(l_j))$ is invertible over $L$.

Comment: Isn’t this the well-known theorem called Independence of Characters? If you know that, you have your proof; if not, maybe you want to look it up?

Comment: By this you mean that when $\chi_1,\ldots, \chi_n$ are distinct characters, they are linearly independent?

Comment: Yes, where “character” here means homomorphism from a commutative group into a field. In our case, the “group” is $L^*$ and the “field” is $L$.

Comment: Yes, so $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$ are linearly independent maps over $L$. How exactly do we conclude that the matrix is invertible? The $\varphi_i$ are not $L$-linear maps.

Comment: Sorry to ask stupidly, but I just don't see why the fact that the $\varphi_i$ are $L$-linearly independent maps $L\to L$ means that the matrix in question is invertible. How does the basis for $L$ over $K$ come into the picture?

Comment: Let me try to put it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will be inefficient and index-heavy. I’m sure you can shorten it.

For the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
\varphi_1(\ell_1)&\varphi_1(\ell_2)&\dots&\varphi_1(\ell_n)\\
\varphi_2(\ell_1)&&\dots&\varphi_2(\ell_n)\\
\vdots&&&\vdots\\
\varphi_n(\ell_1)&&\dots&\varphi_n(\ell_n)
\end{pmatrix}
to fail to be invertible, the rows would be $L$-linearly dependent. That is, we would have $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ in $L$ with $\sum_i\alpha_iR_i=0$, where $R_i$ is the $i$-th row in our matrix. That is, for each $j$, we have $\sum_i\alpha_i\varphi_i(\ell_j)=0$. Now, let $z\in L$, so that $z=\sum_j\beta_j\ell_j$, for scalars $\beta_j\in K$. In $K\,$!

Now we apply the map $\sum_i\alpha_i\varphi_i$ to $z$, pass the $K$-scalars $\beta_j$ through the $\varphi_i$’s, and use the zeroness of $\sum_i\alpha_i\varphi_i(\ell_j)$ to see that $\sum_i\alpha_i\varphi_i(z)=0$, which Independence of Characters tells us can only happen if all the $\alpha_i$’s were zero after all.